# Why are there so many Minecraft questions?

Tags: discussion

Why are there so many Minecraft questions?

I used to play Minecraft ALOT but now I have sort of gone away from it and I came on here to help people with other game and I only really see Minecraft related ones?

Comment: Do note that you can hide questions tagged with the [minecraft] tag by putting it into your 'ignore' list on your profile (Edit Profile & Settings -> Preferences)

Answer (score 9):

**Because it is a popular game**. The game is played by many people, and many people have questions about it. That's all it really comes down to.

Comment: Add to this, Arqade has a ton of great MC answers.  If someone in need of MC technical support needed assistance, Arqade would very likely show up on the top of the search list. (Even though we don't do "tech support".)

It doesn't help that most questions here are use "How do I" or Why does this", making the place match a ton of search queries when guests feel like Mojang isn't listening to them.